# How to get Class Name/Storage type of NSArray or NSSet?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray, nsset

I want to get the storage type of NSArray or NSSet.

For example I defined the property:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet <TestClass > testComments;
```

Now I want to get name of class (TestClass) of NSSet. Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.  Like Java, Objective-C's generics support is compile-time-only.  They are little more than glorified annotations to help the Swift compiler, and the warnings generated by clang are really incidental.

Comment: Thanks avi for valuable information. Is it possible in Swift?

Comment: I can get the Attribute Name like NSSet or NSArray using `class_getProperty` runtime.